# Installing VS2017 from Command Line

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script that will install VS2017. First I need to download the VS install exe using

```
$vs2017Url = # Address to VS2017 download
$vs2017Exe = "${env:Temp}\vs_professional.exe";

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $vs2017Url -OutFile $vs2017Exe;
```

But I cannot find the Url for the VS2017 download: going to the VS website [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-2017-rc/) and right clicking the 'Free Download' button and selecting 'Copy link address...' gives me the following:

```
https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Professional&rel=15
```

but this is not the exe, it appears to be a resource with a lot of html/js. Where can I find the direct Url for the VS2017 install exe download?

Comment: How is this related to programming? You copied the wrong URL. That's not the URL to the executable, that's the *thank you page* that sends the `exe` to you as a file.

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToMakeAnOfflineInstallerForVS2017.aspx

Comment: What are you going to do with the 1MB installer anyway? If you want to generate an offline install check [Create an offline installation of Visual Studio 2017 RC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio). The final version is comes out on Tuesday anyway.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can see it's the wrong URL, I'm trying to work what the right one is, i.e., where is Microsoft's repo for VS exes; I can't seem to find it anywhere. We're stamping out developer VMs on Azure, but looks like I'll have to download exe and store in our repo and pull it from there - probably safer that way.

Comment: @JamesB then wait until Tuesday and generate an *offline setup* as shown in the docs. There is no "right" URL anyway. The page sends a different URL each time, almost certainly from a CDN. Another option is to download the installer once (after Tuesday of course) and add a script to the VM to download and install VS

Comment: You could also chech the [Chocolatey package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/visualstudio2017enterprise) for VS 2017, which essentially downloads the web installer from a URL. The package page displays the contents of the Install.ps1 file with the *current* URL. This will definitely change next week

Comment: I create a powershell script to install visual studio 2017, here is the link: [powershell script](https://github.com/lettucebo/Ci.Convention/blob/master/ENVIRONMENT/ENVIRONMENT-MONEY-INSTALL.ps1#L260) if someone needed